# Solution not getting built in team explorer when I add project outside the solution folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I added a project that is outside the solution folder in the TFS.

Its getting built locally and publishing successfully, but when I build it through the team explorer the newly added project which is outside the solution folder is not getting built

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 3
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {K4J2KL-18FA-40KD-95D4-23023fK}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = http://ipaddress:8080/tfs/track
        SccLocalPath0 = .
        SccProjectUniqueName1 = ProjectName\\ProjectName.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName1 = ProjectName.sln
        SccProjectName1 = ProjectName
        SccLocalPath1 = ProjectName
        SccProjectUniqueName2 = ..\\..\\ProjectName.BusinessEntities\\ProjectName.BusinessEntities.csproj
        SccProjectTopLevelParentUniqueName2 = ProjectName.sln
        SccProjectName2 = ../../ProjectName.BusinessEntities
        SccLocalPath2 = ..\\..\\ProjectName.BusinessEntities
    EndGlobalSection
```

Here when i build the project in team explorer, it says that the `ProjectName.BusinessEntities.csproj` is not found. This class library is two folders above the folder containing the solution in TFS.

Comment: It's because the file remains only local

Comment: how can i make it work?? How should i refer to the project outside the solution folder in tfs??

Comment: Check if the project is under source control

Answer (score 1):

Your workspace mapping for the build definition must include the new project. The build is telling you the truth - it can't find the .csproj file because only those files in the workspace mappings will be fetched - and that doesn't include your new project.

Comment: I added the entity project in the workspace in the working folder section of build definition

Comment: I would increase the logging level and start carefully looking at the logs. You should see where it attempts to do a Get Latest on the workspace, and you'll be able to see what it fetched and where it fetched it to.